# WPF Datagrid bound to ViewModel.DataTable. SelectedItem not binding to ViewModel.SelectedObject

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatable, datagrid

TYFYT. I need some help understanding what's going on here and how binding to a datagrid works.  I am coming from a knowledge base of working with WinForms so maybe my approach is all wrong?...

I have a WPF window, with a Datagrid.
In the ViewModel I have DataTable that I have populated with my Booking objects.  The cols across the top correspond to a TimeSlot, and the row headers correspond to an instructor.

```
void DisplayBookings()
{

    foreach (Booking booking in bookings)
    {   //Add each Booking object to the DataTable
        DtBookings.Rows[booking.GridRow][booking.SlotTimeId + 1] = booking;
    }
}
```

In the window xaml I have the datagrid bound to the DtBookings.

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="grdInstructors" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding DtBookings}" DisplayMemberPath="Id"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCell}"
```

When I run this, it's working fine.   I see the bookings in the correct cells in the grid.

Trying to do work against the grid is what is raising questions.

Q1.  What is the grid cell holding?  I have put the *Booking* objects in the ViewModel.DataTable and in the grid cell I see "myNamespace.Models.Booking".   This is fine but when I try to access it I get the `error "'Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'MyObject' (Booking)`
So is the datagrid only holding a String that is the name of the object?  I could accept that answer since I'm thinking the View should only be a visual representation of the objects.

If that is so, then how should `SelectedItem=ViewModel.MySelectedItem` work?  (In this case it doesn't).  Initially I thought it should have a copy of the object so that when I click on the cell it will tell the ViewModel what object I have chosen.   This normally works when I am bound to an ObservableCollection, but in this case it is bound to a DataTable so I'm not getting the same result.

And on a final note I have noticed that `DisplayMemberPath="Id"` doesn't work in this case.  (It's not really an issue since I usually override `ToString())

It would be great to have a definitive answer on this before I add logic to work around the problem and defeat the point of MVVM and Binding.

TYVM.

Comment: "So is the datagrid only holding a String that is the name of the object?" - no. it was DataTable, which converted Booking object into string. most likely you didn't specify column's DataType (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.datatype?view=net-6.0#remarks)

Comment: @RayBrennan: Why is `DtBookings` a `DataTable`? Then `SelectedCell` should be a `DataRowView`. Don't add custom objects to a `DataTable` if that's what you are trying to do.